# How to fix [nan] output from csv file?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I’m trying to work with a very large csv file (15,500) that contains a Date, Time (HH:MM), Name, High, Low as the fields. Ideally this project will give me time bins for the data to show me what time the highest and lowest priced item tends to sell. The first step I’ve tried is to simply get the data into python and I’m encountering issues already. Before I can even begin to think about how to accomplish the end goal I’m stuck. I'm obviously so new at this, so please be kind...`

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt('http://localhost:8888/edit/Downloads/sales.csv', delimiter= " , ", invalid_raise = False)


print (my_data)
```

**output**

```
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan]
```

At this step I'd just like to see that my data has been imported correctly.

The next step I believe will be to find the max and min for each date, then figure out which time those happened.

Would that just be a for loop for the date, then an embedded for loop to find max and min?

I'd like a simple histograph of the time bins on the bottom to show if there is a time when the most expensive item sells and when the least expensive item sells (the data is already in 5min buckets).

Comment: Are you sure `genfromtxt` can accept URLs?

Comment: Use Pandas package's read_csv function. If any columns in your csv are still not parsed correctly by default, you can pass in a dictionary of column-name to datatype, but usually this function's defaults are pretty good. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces around the ",", try removing these. Additionally, try to add dtype=None, encoding='utf-8'. So try:

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt('Downloads/sales.csv', delimiter=",", dtype=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

Additionally, if the CSV has headers, you could try adding `names=True`. If you do that, you can access them by doing `my_data['header_name']`. (And (500,15) does not sound that large, numpy can deal with much larger arrays.)
And you should not use the Jupyter notebook url for loading that file. Just change the path to the proper filename.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. As you can tell I really have no clue how to start to apply this stuff in the real world. I ordered the book 'Python for Data Analysis' to help.